# Probability of symmetric difference inequality

Tags: probability

I think I am missing something easy here, but my book notes that
$$P\left\{\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \mathbin\triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j\right\} \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty P\{A_j \mathbin\triangle B_j\}$$
where $A\mathbin\triangle B$ is the symmetric difference of the two sets $A,B$. It seems some what intuitive as the sets may overlap and the right hand side will be greater in that case, no? I have tried to write the symmetric difference of the unions as disjoint subsets of the union of symmetric differences, and then use additivity and $P(A) \leq P(B)$ for $A\subset B$ (despite this fact being proven after the original note, not that I think it depends on this) but did not succeed.

Any suggestions or hints would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\omega\in A_i$ and $\omega\not\in\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j$.  Then $\omega$ is a member of *none* of the sets $B_j$, $j=1,2,3,\ldots\,$.  Therefore $\omega\in A_i\mathbin\triangle B_i$.  And so $\omega\in\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\mathbin\triangle B_j$. And the same thing applies if $\omega\in B_j$ and $\omega\not\in\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$.  Thus we have
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \mathbin\triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \mathbin\triangle B_j.
$$
Consequently
$$
P\left\{\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \mathbin\triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j\right\} \leq P\left\{ \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\mathbin\triangle B_j \right\}.
$$
Lastly, we have
$$
P\left\{ \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\mathbin\triangle B_j \right\} \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty P\{A_j \mathbin\triangle B_j\}.
$$

Comment: Thank you the beginning was what I had missed, but also why is the last inequality true? Just the fact that the probability of an union is less than the the sum of the probabilities from the union? My book does not prove this, seems like something one should do first before this fact.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 : \begin{align}
& P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots) \\  \\
= {} & P\Big( A_1 \cup \Big(A_2\setminus A_1\Big) \cup \Big(A_3 \setminus (A_1\cup A_2)\Big) \cup \Big( A_4 \setminus (A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3) \Big) \cup \cdots \Big) \\
& \text{(Here, at each step we add only as much of the next set as has not been added earlier.)} \\  \\
= {} & P(A_1) + P(A_2\setminus A_1) + P(A_3\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)) + P(A_4 \setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)) + \cdots \\  \\
\le {} & P(A_1) + P(A_2) + P(A_3) + P(A_4) + \cdots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The LHS is points in some $A_i$ and no $B_j$, points in the RHS are in some $A_i$ and not $B_i$ specifically, so you're not cutting away all the points in $A_i\setminus B_j$ for $j\ne i$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at the base case.
$$\begin{align}(A_1\cup A_2)\triangle(B_1\cup B_2)
 & = ((A_1\cup A_2)\cap B_1^c \cap B_2^c)\cup(A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap(B_1\cup B_2))
\\[1ex] & = (A_1\cap B_1^c\cap B_2^c)\cup(A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap B_2)\cup (A_2\cap B_1^c\cap B_2^c)\cup (A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap B_1)
\\[1ex] & \subseteq (A_1\cap B_1^c)\cup(A_1^c\cap B_1)\cup(A_2\cap B_2^c)\cup(A_2^c\cap B_2)
\\[2ex]\therefore (A_1\cup A_2)\triangle(B_1\cup B_2) & \subseteq (A_1\triangle B_1)\cup(A_2\triangle B_2)
\end{align}$$

Now let look at the inductive step.

$$\begin{align} \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j\;\cup A_{n+1}\right)\triangle\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n B_j\;\cup B_{n+1}\right) & \subseteq \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j \triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^n B_j\right)\cup(A_{k+1}\triangle B_{k+1})
\end{align}$$

And we can clearly see where that is going.   Thus we argue that because it is true for two, and inductive step also holds, therefore it shall be true for more, *ad infinitum*.

Then we apply measure theory to this result and reach the requisite conclusion.

$\Box$